# Printing variables in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, pandas, csv, variables, tkinter

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

label1= Label(master, text='Department')
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

textBox = Text(master, height=1, width=10)
textBox.grid(row=0, column=1)

def retrieve_input():
    Department = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c") 

    fileread = pd.read_csv('50.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    filevalue = fileread.loc[fileread['Customer'].str.contains(Department, na=False)]    



    def printSomething():
        label = Label(master, textvariable=filevalue)
        label.grid(row=3, column=1) 



button1 = Button(master,text="Show Values", command=lambda: retrieve_input())
button1.grid(row=2, column=1)

mainloop( )
```

I have searched around Stack Overflow of how to do this, and was able to construct my code up until this point, However when I click the Show values button, nothing happens. I could find nowhere online that helped address this issue. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code? Using Python 3.7

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: could you also provide the contents of your `50.csv` file?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Python 3.7

Comment: As a side note: `lambda: retrieve_input()` is just a function that, when called, does `retrieve_input()`. You don't need this; you can just pass `command=retrieve_input` directly,  Because when `retrieve_input` gets called as `retrieve_input()`, that obviously just does `retrieve_input()`.

Comment: @abarnert I currently have my code with lamda because this is just a test code, I have several more inputs I need to also put in, and from my understanding and testing around with code, it only works when lamda is inserted like this

Comment: If you need to pass extra arguments, then yes, you need to define a zero-argument function to pass as `command`—whether you do that with `lambda`, `def`, or `functools.partial` doesn't really matter, but you need one of them.

Comment: Please post a sample CSV file as text. If you want anyone to actually debug your code rather than just make suggestions, we need to be able to copy and paste your `.py` file and your `.csv` file and run it and see your issue. Read [mcve] in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a nested `printSomething` function that would display something, but you never call that function.

This would fix that problem:

```
def retrieve_input():
    Department = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c") 

    fileread = pd.read_csv('50.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    filevalue = fileread.loc[fileread['Customer'].str.contains("Lam Dep", na=False)]    

    def printSomething():
        label = Label(master, textvariable=filevalue)
        label.grid(row=3, column=1) 

    printSomething()
```

But I'm not sure why you need the function in the first place; you can just do this:

```
def retrieve_input():
    Department = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c") 

    fileread = pd.read_csv('50.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    filevalue = fileread.loc[fileread['Customer'].str.contains("Lam Dep", na=False)]    

    label = Label(master, textvariable=filevalue)
    label.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

---

But you have a second problem: You're trying to set the `textvariable=filevalue`, but that doesn't make any sense.

The `textvariable` has to be a `tkinter.StringVar` instance, not a plain old Python string. You can then `set` the `StringVar` to hold your string.

```
    filevar = StringVar()
    filevar.set(filevalue)
    label = Label(master, textvariable=filevar)
    label.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

… or just pass the text in directly, without a tkinter variable:

```
    label = Label(master, text=filevalue)
    label.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

---

There's still one more problem: Every time you call `retrieveInput`, it's going to create a new `Label` and grid it in front of whatever used to be there, but you never delete the old ones. So if you press the button over and over again, there will be a whole stack of invisible widgets just wasting resources.

It probably makes more sense to move the label creation to the global scope, just like the text box and the other label, and replace its text in this function, instead of creating a new label each time.

Using a `StringVar` is the simplest way to do this:

```
# ...

textBox = Text(master, height=1, width=10)
textBox.grid(row=0, column=1)

fileVar = StringVar()
fileLabel = Label(master, textvariable=fileVar)
fileLabel.grid(row=3, column=1)

def retrieve_input():
    Department = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c") 

    fileread = pd.read_csv('50.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    filevalue = fileread.loc[fileread['Customer'].str.contains("Lam Dep", na=False)]    

    fileVar.set(filevalue)

# ...
```

You may have other bugs in your code, but I think if you fix these three, you'll at least be pretty close to everything working.

Comment: That makes sense for sure! I ran this code and still nothing is being produced on my GUI.

Comment: @HarisKhaliq Which code did you run? I have 5 fragments of code in this answer; you need to integrate the fix for all three problems into your code. And if you get something wrong, or just have another bug beyond this one, I can't debug it for you without a complete example.

Comment: I had not seen the other fragments, I will read this carefully, try to understand it, and integrate it with my code. Youre explanation was very logical and made sense for sure. Thank you.

Comment: Oh wow, I already got it to work, and thought I would be stuck on this for hours. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are running Python 3.7, as you said, the following code will solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

label1= Label(master, text='Department')
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

textBox = Text(master, height=1, width=10)
textBox.grid(row=0, column=1)

def retrieve_input():
    global text
    department = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    fileread = pd.read_csv('50.csv', encoding='latin-1')

    filevalue = fileread.loc[fileread['Customer'].str.contains("Lam Dep", na=False)]

    text.set(filevalue)


button1 = Button(master,text="Show Values", command=retrieve_input)
button1.grid(row=2, column=1)
text = StringVar()
label = Label(master, textvariable=text)
label.grid(row=0, column=1)


mainloop()
```

You are facing these problems:

1. You are defining an inner function `printSomething` which is never called.
2. Even if you were calling `printSomething` you are going to create a new `Label` every time you press `button1`.
3. In this as, you don't need to use lambda to pass the callback that will be executed, you can simply pass `command=retrieve_input`

The simplest solution might be to define a `StringVar` (`text`) which is going to be associated with a `Label` (`label`), and when you press the button `button1` you update call the method `set` on that variable `text`.